# Почему при использовании оператора && программа заходит в блок if а при использовании опреатора || не заходит

Tags: c++

Почему когда я пишу

```
 while (num>0) {
if (num % 10 != 3 && num % 10 != 6) {
OriginNum += num % 10 * check;
check *= 10;
}
num /= 10;
}
}
```

тогда при num%10 будет равно 3 или 6 оно не зайдёт в блок if
а когда  вместо && пишу ||

```
 while (num>0) {
if (num % 10 != 3 || num % 10 != 6) {
OriginNum += num % 10 * check;
check *= 10;
}
num /= 10;
}
}
```

программа заходит в if даже когда num%10 равен 3 или 6

по идее в первом же случае проверяет 6 не равно 3 и 6 не равно 6 - результат false (не заходит в if)
а во втором случае проверяет 6 не равно 3 или 6 не равно 6 - результат тоже false потому что 6=6

Так вот ещё раз вопрос почему в втором случае результат не false и программа заходит в if

Кому надо вот весь код

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    int num, OriginNum=0;
    int check=1;

    cout << "I can output number without 3 and 6" << endl;
    cout << "Enter number:";
        cin >> num;

        while (num>0) {
            if (num % 10 != 3 || num % 10 != 6) {
                OriginNum += num % 10 * check;
                check *= 10;
            }
            num /= 10;
        }
}
```

Comment: *"6 не равно 3 или 6 не равно 6 - результат тоже false"* - результат будет true так как 6 не равно 3, причем проверка на равенство 6 даже не будет выполнятся, вот и все

Comment: А понял спасибо я то думал (почему-то не написал) что оно даёт true а во втором false и типа flase сильнее true ну короче спасибо открыл глаза

Comment: Можешь написать его как ответ мне из всех он наиболее понятен и короток (остальным тоже спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

**Если число не 3 и не 6** — но оно же может быть таким? скажем, 5?

**Если число не 3 или не 6** — Какое бы число мы не взяли, оно будет либо не 3, либо не 6, либо и не 3, и не 6. Т.е. это выражение всегда истинно...

```
Если это 3 — оно не 6, ура!  
Если это 6 — оно не 3, снова ура :)  
Если это 1,2,4,5,7 etc — оно таки не 3, и дальше можно и не проверять.
```

Так понятно?

См. также https://ideone.com/2LgmaD

Answer (score 1):

```
if (num % 10 != 3 && num % 10 != 6) {
```

соответствует

```
if (!(num % 10 == 3 || num % 10 == 6)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

- Если хоть одно из условий является истинным, то логический оператор
  `||` ("или") вернет истину.

Проверяется одно условие _ если это истина(не 3 в данном случаи), то второе     условие и не нужно проверять, потому что уже одно из условий есть       истина, и оператор вернет `true`. (Именно исходя из того, что может быть проверено только одно условие, часто    этот оператор предпочтительней оператора `&&`( "И"). Почему часто и не всегда? Это уже другой вопрос...

**Если же первое условие не выполняется  (если это 3), то проверяется истинность второго условия. И если оно тоже не верно, то только в этом случаи оператор вернет** `false`(то есть когда ни одно из условий не выполняется)

А второе условие,  в вашем случаи, конечно выполнится, потому что если дело дошло до него, значит это число заканчивается тройкой и, естественно, не заканчивается шестеркой. Это равносильно тому, чтобы вместо этого оператора написать `true`. Поэтому ваши условия не разумны. И тут на помощь приходит логический оператор `&&`("И").

1. Логический оператор `&&`("И") вернет `true` только если оба операнда
   истины. То есть, в любом случаи проверяются оба условия, и если хоть
   одно из условий не верно, оператор вернет `false`.

А значит, в вашем случаи, оператор `num % 10 != 3 && num % 10 != 6` истина, если это число  заканчивается **не тройкой и не шестеркой** И `false`, если результат 3 или 6, то  если вы хотите написать аналог этого оператора посредством логического **ИЛИ**, то смотрите ответ от `Igor`, где просто сказано что это **не**(3 или 6)